# Book about programming in Windows 7

Tags: c++, windows-7

Could anyone recommend good book about programming in windows 7 in C++?

Comment: Programming for Windows 7, or just general C++ programming in a Windows 7 environment? I'm probably ignorant of this, but I don't see why programming in a Windows 7 environment would be much different than Vista or even XP.

Comment: @Jesse they introduced Direct2D and DirectWrite in Windows 7 as successors of GDI+

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not a book in the classical sense, but it is great, extremely comprehensive when it comes to the Windows API (all new Windows 7 technologies are covered), and normative: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/sv-se/library/ff381399(en-us,VS.85).aspx).

Comment: Deffo. MSDN is sublime. Most comprehensive help service available. It contains examples, source code, tutorials and API documentation. can be a bit scary to get around at first though.

Comment: I do agree that MSDN is ok but somewhat lack of good thorough explanation like for example in Petzold's book where he explains every detail and what we need it for etc. You won't find it in MSDN.

Answer (score 1):

Programming is the same in Windows 7 as in any other (NT) version of Windows.
The only possible differences are newer header files and changes in the APIs.
I don't think that there is a book about them.

Comment: MSDN got all the news, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any particular reason you're specifically referring to Windows 7? On a general level, windows programs don't work much differently than they did a decade ago. Taking advantage of windows 7's features just means familiarizing yourself with the new APIs.

If you don't know windows programming to begin with, I'd recommend [Programming Windows](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/157231995X).

If you already do windows programming, [Introducing Windows 7 for Developers](http://www.amazon.com/Introducing-Windows-Developers-Yochay-Kiriaty/product-reviews/0735626820/ref=dp_top_cm_cr_acr_txt?ie=UTF8&showViewpoints=1) may be more up your alley.